# Class as an input in a function

Tags: python, class, input

I have a file `different_classes` that contains three different classes. It is something like:

```
class first(object):
    def __init__(x, y, z):
    body of the first class

class second(first):
    def __init__(x, y, z, a=2, b=3):
    body of the second class

class third(object):
    def __init__(x, y, z):
    body of the third class
```

Now I have another file, say `main.py` where I want to be able to pass on the name of the class that needs to be called. For example, right now I do:

```
import different_classes
def create_blah():
    instance = different_classes.first()
    rest of the function body
```

when I want to use the first class in `different_classes`. If I want to use class `second`, I use different_classes.second().

Can I input the class name as an argument in the `create_blah` function. Something like:

```
def create_blah(class_type = "first", x=x1, y=y1, z=z1):
    instance = different_classes.class_type(x, y, z)
```

I know this may not be valid...but want to know if something similar can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than passing the name of the class, why not just pass the class itself:

```
def create_blah(class_type = different_classes.first, x=x1, y=y1, z=z1):
    instance = class_type(x, y, z)
```

Remember that a class is just an object like anything else in Python: you can assign them to variables and pass them around as arguments.

If you really do need to use the name, e.g. because you are reading it from a configuration file, then use `getattr()` to retrieve the actual class:

```
instance = getattr(different_classes, class_type)(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can pass the class as you have suggested. Did not know that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_blah(class_type = "first", x=x1, y=y1, z=z1):
  class_ = different_classes.__dict__.get(class_type, None)
  if isinstance(class_, type):
    instance = class_(x, y, z)
```

You could also pass around the class object: `class_ = different_classes.first`.

Comment: Not explicitly incorrect, but the example code is an example of doing it wrong(tm) - therefore, aiming for a total score of 0, I downvoted.

Comment: @delnan I answered the original poster's question.  I didn't know if he was receiving his class name as a string or not.  I do this stuff all the time to implement factory methods in Python.

Comment: You might also instead use `class_ = getattr(different_classes, class_type, None)`.

Answer (score -1):

Sort of. Thare are fancier ways, but I suggest this one.

```
def create_blah(class_type = "first", x=x1, y=y1, z=z1):
    if class_type == "first":
        instance=different_classes.first(x,y,z)
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the -3? I said there are fancier ways. This is a perfectly legitimate way of doing this.